# How to call std function passed as template parameter to class?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have a class like this

```
template <typename T>
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(T& outputProcessor):
        _output(outputProcessor){}
protected:
    void processData(int data){
        std::map<std::string,int> output;

        //T(output); ??
    }
    T& _output;
};
```

And then I'm creating it:

```
Foo< decltype (processOutput) >(processOutput)
```

`processOutput` is defined as

```
std::function<void(std::map<std::string, int>)> processOutput;
```

Can I call `T` from `Foo`, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative implementation, you can inherit privately from `T` as it follows:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo: private T {
public:
    Foo(T outputProcessor):
        T(std::move(outputProcessor)) { }
protected:
    void processData(int data) {
        std::map<std::string,int> output;
        (*this)(output);
        // Or: T::operator()(output);
    }
};
```

This way, the `outputProcessor` policy becomes part of the `Foo` class, as it ought to be.

You can still construct an instance of `Foo` as it follows:

```
int main() {
    std::function<void(std::map<std::string, int>)> processOutput = [](std::map<std::string, int>){};
    Foo< decltype (processOutput) > foo(processOutput);
}
```

Or using directly the lambda function:

```
int main() {
    auto processOutput = [](std::map<std::string, int>){};
    Foo< decltype (processOutput) > foo(processOutput);
}
```

No `std::function` is actually required to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `T`, `T` is a type. You can call an *instance* of it, yes.

In your case, `_output` is an instance of `T`, so you can call it like a normal function:

```
_output(output); //Call function in '_output' and passes 'output' as parameter.
```

Comment: Oh. My inattention. I need a break

Comment: Of course just make sure that the reference is still valid at the moment of the call.